# PHP - How To make a search function To search if query match any value

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I am Trying to make search function on my website i use GET

So i want if user search  "How To develop php script in a few seconds With mysql"

It shouldn't mind how long or short or Ascending or descending the search is like if the post title that exists it table is "developing php With mysql"  So far 'develop, PHP, and, mysql' exist in any title i want it To list all post having such title

So i use

`mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog,forum WHERE (`title`LIKE '%".$_GET['search']."%')");`

The result only bring the one that match how it is writing or only if the word before Space match like "develop"   or "php"

I will like To do it like google own which doesn't mind your spelling or how it is written To make display of look alike search

I tried but don't work

Comment: Please read up on **SQL Injection**. This code highly vulnerable!

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension **a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: While those comments are valuable, I think the code demonstrates the intention very well. No reason to overcomplicate things here.

Comment: I am an upcoming developer So that is why

I use mysql_query

Comment: This Code do not search like i want

Comment: @AdesanoyeAdeleyeBenjamin look into natural language searches